# Getting mingw-gcc not recognized when trying to install using luarocks

Tags: windows, lua, luarocks

I have lua in my path and luarocks is in the same folder in Program Files. I'm trying to install `luafilesystem` and I am receiving this error.

```
PS C:\Users\Owner> luarocks install luafilesystem
Installing https://luarocks.org/luafilesystem-1.8.0-1.src.rock

luafilesystem 1.8.0-1 depends on lua >= 5.1 (5.3-1 provided by VM)
mingw32-gcc -O2 -c -o src/lfs.o -IC:\Program Files\lua/include src/lfs.c
'mingw32-gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Error: Build error: Failed compiling object src/lfs.o
PS C:\Users\Owner>
```

I tried installing `mingw64` through the installer on mingw site thinking that would work as a fix, but it gives a "downloaded incorrectly" error in the installer. Also tried installing mingw using msys and that seemed to install but still getting the same error trying to install `luafilesystem`

Comment: You should type build commands in the special MSYS console window, not in the PowerShell window.

Answer (score 2):

If gcc is installed and in your Path, I was able to fix this error by renaming my `gcc.exe` compiler to `mingw32-gcc.exe` before running the `luarocks install` command. It's a bit hacky but I haven't run into any issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

Installing mingw should indeed solve the issue, but it doesn't end there. I have installed mingw, and gcc is simply called `gcc` (not `mingw32-gcc`), therefore the error persists. You may check if that is your problem as well.

A solution that I deemed good enough was switching to MSVC and running luarocks from the developer command prompt: luarocks should automatically detect the compiler and use it, but if you want to use gcc you should look for how to solve that naming issue.